# Please create tag 'techfolios'

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

I have just released a new open source system for technical portfolios:

http://techfolios.github.io/

Could someone with sufficient authority please create the tag 'techfolios' so that I can use Stack OverFlow for Q&A?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support. Do you have a question already to which we can add the tag?

Answer (score 22):

Tags are created when questions are asked, not preemptively.

Looking at your site, I'm not immediately clear on what sort of developer Q&A would be needed... but if/when someone has a question about it, the tag can be created at that point.

As far as using Stack Overflow for Q&A goes, be sure to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support if you haven't already. It explains how to make SO a good place for dev support related to your product without alienating the community here.